# How to create an animated map?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, geoserver, animation, spatio-temporal-data

I am seeking to create an animated map illustrating the simultaneous movement of different objects across a large area over time.

The display should be capable of playing automatically, or by manually selecting a date and/or period.

I would like to retain the interrogable capability of a digital map (zoom and query a database or attributes) while paused, so I do not want to merely create raster images and and incorporate them into a slide show.

Rather I want vector data moving across a base map.

Does anyone know how to perform this trick using QGIS, GeoServer or ArcGIS for Desktop?

Answer (score 6):

Here are two options:

[QGIS - Animating Time Series Data](https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/animating_time_series.html)

[ArcGIS - Visualize temporal data using the time slider](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/mapping/time/visualize-temporal-data-using-the-time-slider.htm)

Comment: Both of these are good options. I think the QGIS version has a little more functionality, but the ArcGIS option seems more stable. Mind you this is more of a recollection on my part. It's definitely worth trying both to see which is optimal. If you just wanted something very compelling to watch in motion, CartoDB's [Torque](http://cartodb.github.io/torque/) is hard to beat.

Answer (score 4):

Geoserver has an animated gif option:
http://geo-solutions.blogspot.com/2011/11/animate-your-maps-with-geoserver.html

but it doesn't give you an interface, to create an interface you should use a javascript library like OpenLayers, check for example the timeslider in GXP:

http://gxp.opengeo.org/master/examples/time-viewer.html