# Examples of Animated maps

Tags: qgis, google-earth, animation

I am currently looking examples of animated maps. Creating animated maps with the help of [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24899/how-to-create-an-animated-map) post and [similar post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26546/openlayers-animation-examples-and-algorithms) checking [Animaps site](http://www.animaps.com) also

I am presenting this map in local school so those students should take interest to learn and create various simple interactive maps.

I am in process to create animated map contains Gardens and amusement parks across the city.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One of the most spectacular animated maps I've seen is [Google's Wind Map](http://hint.fm/wind/).

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Some great examples in the links there! One thing not mentioned in your links, which should be useful, is OpenLayers' [Strategy.Refresh](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Strategy/Refresh-js.html) call.  In this you can set a time interval for refreshing a vector layer automatically.

Also, I create 3D animated landscape visualizations for public participation in planning and they are stand-alone (not web-based), so I don't know if you'd call that a 'map' as such. However, you may also get some inspiration from 3D mapping and tech in [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/50020/examples-of-3-d-maps/50032#50032) thread.

Comment: thanks for the answer : ) I am looking for more examples so I will keep open this question for one or two days.

Answer (score 2):

Based in QGIS

Underdarks's Tutorial

> ```
> Layer “start_flash” is a medium sized dot that marks the appearance of a new tweet.
> Layer “big_flash” is a bigger dot of the same color which will appear after “start_flash”.
> Layer “permanent” is a small dot that will be visible even after the flash vanishes.
> ```

http://anitagraser.com/2011/11/20/nice-animations-with-time-managers-offset-feature/

Comment: ♦ thanks for the ans : ) In my city (Pune,India) QGIS is using in schools to create very simple maps : )

Answer (score 2):

See these examples mainly related to transportation

- [UK London tube](http://traintimes.org.uk/map/tube/)
- [Netherland example](http://kubus.mailspool.nl/spoorkaart/)
- [Switzerland example](http://www.swisstrains.ch/)
- [Leaflet animated marker plugin](http://openplans.github.io/Leaflet.AnimatedMarker/)

PS: Not Qgis related but can answer to the need